# Database Updating and images retrieving from the sd card in android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-sdcard

i am trying to find the solution for this problem but i could not found the answer. I have a database that stores the details of some user details, i.e., id, name and user pic URLs. and am storing the images in sdcard. when the user login all the details are stored and images are downloaded to sdcard. And now when another user login to the application i want to delete all the previous details and store new user details.

And By using the below code am able to get one pic from the sdcard, and when i try it for a list view. I am not able to see the images.

```
File mfile = new File("sdcard/Image9085.png");
    if(mfile.exists()){
        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mfile.getAbsolutePath());
        pic.setImageBitmap(picture);
    }
```

Can any one please help me in doing these both problems.

Answer (score 2):

image path maybe wrong, should like below:

```
File mfile = new File("/sdcard/Image9085.png");
if(mfile.exists()){
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mfile.getAbsolutePath());
    pic.setImageBitmap(picture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ListView use CustomAdapter means Create a class which extends BaseAdapter 
Within getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            View view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null);
            if(mykids_data.get(position).getImage()!=null)
            {
                Download dr=new Download();
                dr.iv=img;
                dr.execute();
                //img.setImageDrawable(dr.d);
            }
//              
            return view;
        }
```

Use a class Download which extends AsyncTask 
within doinBackground function just use the

```
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {


     File mfile = new File("sdcard/Image9085.png");
        if(mfile.exists()){
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mfile.getAbsolutePath());


  Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(picture);

                             d=drawable;
                    }
```

Comment: And one more thing, i gave names to the downloaded pictures randomly, so how can i retrieve images for the same details?

Comment: randomly means? you can do one thing whenever you are naming images that time only use one arraylist<String> imagenames store that name in the arraylist

Comment: Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
Image_name = "Channel_Image-"+n+".png";
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/Images/"+Image_name); Am using this for storing images with random names

Comment: Random generator = new Random(); int n = 10000; n = generator.nextInt(n); Image_name = "Channel_Image-"+n+".png";imagenames.add(Image_name);wer imagenames is an arraylist

Comment: when am trying to store these values in Database, it storing null values.